# Java => ActiveX component = Swing with no interaction

Tags: java, swing, activex, javabeans, tstcon32

I'm creating a Java bean component and then generate it to ActiveX dll like in this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/beans/axbridge/developerguide/index.html)

It is a `Swing` panel

```
public class AACWCSurvey extends javax.swing.JPanel
```

with couple `JButton`s

but when I test it in tstcon32.exe I can't actually press any button (JButton). It's like a picture.

What's wrong?

Thank you

**upd:** tried with AWT (java.awt.Panel, java.awt.Button) - same story. You see it, but you can't press the buttons

[image]

Comment: please certainly it isn't riddle, because I lost in your puzzle, are you meaning Windows ActiveX Object,

Comment: @mKorbel yes, ActiveX control http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX

Comment: hmmm good luck with that, because I had lots of problems with those Object in MsOffice or C++, isn't there another way, simpler, without complicating things by using ActiveX in Jave or vice versa

Comment: Don't go down that road. Java and ActiveX are not a good fit. The Bridge does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a project called iKVM.  It lets you use the .net framework from Java.

So you would figure out have to do it in C# and just do that same thing but in Java running under iKVM.

Come on its good enough give me 50 points :)

Seriously Good luck.  I'm learning C# now it's actually pretty nice.